# How to call Logic App from MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-logic-apps

Can some one please share how to call logic apps from MVC application?

My requirement is pass data from web form to logic apps http request.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Now i'm able to call / trigger logic app url from MVC application. And i could pass json data to logic app url . Following is my code.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Add_recordAsync(register rs)
{

     using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
            
         var jsonData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
         {
                
             email = "maruthikiran@gmail.com",
             due = rs.Name,
             task = rs.Password
         });
         var content = new StringContent(jsonData);
         content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = string.Empty;
         content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "application/json";
         var response = await client.PostAsync("Logic App URL", content);
     }
}
```

Reference link :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=dotnet#more-resources